# No Boot Device Available

Tags: boot

I have a Dell Vostro 230 Windows 7 computer and recently the hard drive was starting to fail. I then purchased a new hard drive in order to replace the redundant hard drive.

I installed the new hard drive (along side the failing one) and installed Windows 7 on the new hard drive. So now I have two hard drives (new and failing one) each with Windows 7 on it. When both of them are plugged in i can boot to either one. When i boot to my new one it works just fine.

Now here's the issue. When i remove the failing hard drive and just leave the new one in there, upon booting it says 'No Boot Device Available'.

I then checked the BIOS settings and it all seems to be correct. The boot order is correct. The BIOS seems to recognize the new disk as it has the new disk already selected.

Please direct me on what i should do next. Bear in mind this is a brand new hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you take a snapshot even if via a smartphone of your bios boot options and the front page? I may be able to diagnose it. Else try to reseast the hdd. Put the new one in the old slot and see if that makes a difference. If it doesn't leave the new one in the old slot, and put the old one in the new one, restart your machine and see if it can boot. If it does, try cloning you old hard drive using a software like the one from this website [EaseUS Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/). After cloning, remove the old hdd, leaving only the new one in and see if it will boot. There is a chance the MBR in your new HDD may not be configured or installed properly. With that software it can clone an entire OS from primary HDD to secondary HDD with exact partitions and MBR files too.

Comment: I am unable to post a picture as i need 10 reputation points (pretty useless!).

Comment: Do you have an email address? Maybe i can send them to you? @Shivarn

Comment: I've already tried swapping the disks in different slots and using different SATA cables. I guess i could try again. I was unable to clone the disk, my old disk has bad sectors. Therefore, whenever i tried cloning, it would just fail.

Comment: Does this issue have anything to do with master (primary) and slave (secondary) configuration? @Shivarn

Comment: When a `No Boot Device Available` comes up, it generally means that the hdd MBR(Master Boot Record) is either configured incorrectly or the partition of the drive is not set to primary.  The MBR hold files that includes a bootloader. If this bootloader is not installed properly then the drive wont boot. To fix this issue, you could always follow the suggestion of @Journeyman Geek or try a  program such as Acronis True Image, which clones the drive with its MBR and bootloaders.

Comment: Okay yes, all starting to make sense now. So if i've installed Windows 7 on my new HDD using the installation disk, does it automatically install the MBR? If so, does that mean i just have to set the partition of the new HDD to primary?

Comment: Here is what I suggest you do. Before making changes to the partition, lets try and see if fixing the MBR and bootloader will fix the problem. If it doesn't then we can either fiddle with partitions or I've got a couple of other methods you can try.  If you have an installation disk use it to access command prompt from startup, then in `cmd` type `bootrec/fixmbr` followed by `bootrec /fixboot` followed by `bootrect /scanos` to ensure you have an operating system installed and finally type `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. Reboot your machine and see if it will boot.

Comment: Okay, i went away from this computer to the computer with the issue and i've already made the new hard drive's partition as active (primary). So i've only just read your suggestion.

But now it's giving me a different error 'BOOTMGR is missing'.
So what i will do now is try your suggestion. I will open up CMD from startup using an installation disk and follow your steps from there.

Just to clarify - are there any risks here?

Comment: If it's simply the `BOOTMGR is missing` then no.  But to be on the safe side, make sure there is nothing you need or at least have a back up of any files you have on that hdd before attempting. It's better to be safe than sorry before attempting things like this.

Comment: Okay, for some reason I cannot get to the command prompt, it's acting as if there's no OS installed on the new HDD. So now i am installing the OS again and hopefully i will then be able to get to the command prompt. Will keep you updated once i have done this.

Comment: Didn't you use a bootable Windows 7 OS or Windows 7 CD to install? You should be able get to CMD using the disk or bootable win7.

Comment: I am using an Windows 7 Re-installation disk. It's half way through the installation process so I'll just wait it out.

Comment: Ok, all the best :)

Comment: Cheers!! :D I would give your post a vote. . . . but i don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: That's ok. Whenever you get permission to do so, you can do it then if you feel my answer was helpful to you. Also please do not forget to tick the most appropriate answer you found for your issue that was listed.

Comment: SUCCESS!! Shivarn the installation has completed and the OS installed successfully. I am now able to boot using the new hard drive (old one is not plugged in). I've restarted the machine to confirm this and it booted perfectly :D !! So i guess the re-installation of the OS must have installed the MBR again (correct?). Thanks for your help @Shivarn and Journeyman Geek . This is the first time I've used this website, and i must say i am very pleased! Thanks again!!

Comment: Your very welcome :) yup that's right reinstalling the OS freshly again does the trick most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't manage to actually boot the bootloader into the new drive. Boot with both drives in place, and assuming your new windows install is c:

`bootsect /nt60 c: /force /mbr` to force windows to install a new mbr into c:

`bcdboot c:\windows /s c:` to install bcd should do the trick I believe.

Shutdown, unplug the old drive and try again.

If this seems scary, [visualbcd](http://www.boyans.net/) seems to have a tool that does it for you

Comment: Ahhhh I see, makes sense. So how should this be done? Do i have to open CMD once the computer has booted and i have logged in? Or do i have to insert an installation disk and get to the CMD through there? And also, which of the two commands you've posted above should i use?

Comment: yup - in an admin terminal, in that order.